# Google Sheets to Excel Formula Conversion Issue

Tags: excel, transition, array-formulas

I am converting some of my spreadsheets from the Google Sheets format to Excel. When I try to use the following formulas in Excel I receive the "Value" error. Are these formulas not available in Excel and if so, how do I convert it to the Excel Format?

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B7,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,2,FALSE)),"",IF(OR(VLOOKUP($B7,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,6,FALSE)="Finished", VLOOKUP($B7,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,3,FALSE)="Outbound"),IF(ISNA(INDEX(OTI!$A:$O,MATCH($B7&"Yes",OTI!$B:$B&OTI!$N:$N,0),3)),"",INDEX(OTI!$A:$O,MATCH($B7&"Yes",OTI!$B:$B&OTI!$N:$N,0),3)),VLOOKUP($B7,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,2,FALSE)))

=if(isna(index(OTI!$A:$O,match($B10&"Yes",OTI!$B:$B&OTI!$N:$N,0),4)),"",index(OTI!$A:$O,match($B10&"Yes",OTI!$B:$B&OTI!$N:$N,0),4))

=if(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B10,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,4,false)),"",if(or(VLOOKUP($B10,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,6,false)="Finished", VLOOKUP($B10,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,3,false)="Outbound"),if(isna(index(OTI!$A:$O,match($B10&"Yes",OTI!$B:$B&OTI!$N:$N,0),6)),"",index(OTI!$A:$O,match($B10&"Yes",OTI!$B:$B&OTI!$N:$N,0),6)),VLOOKUP($B10,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,4,false)))

=if(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B10,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,5,false)),"",if(or(VLOOKUP($B10,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,6,false)="Finished",VLOOKUP($B10,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,6,false)="Passed Off"),if(isna(index(OTI!$A:$O,match($B10&"Yes",OTI!$B:$B&OTI!$N:$N,0),15)),"",index(OTI!$A:$O,match($B10&"Yes",OTI!$B:$B&OTI!$N:$N,0),15)),VLOOKUP($B10,'Load Tracker'!$A:$F,5,false)))
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try finalizing them with [ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)+[shift](/questions/tagged/shift)+[enter](/questions/tagged/enter) (*aka* CSE). The `OTI!$B:$B&OTI!$N:$N` make them **array formulas**.

You will also want to cut down the full column references or suffer severe calculation lag. You can hardcode a range like,

```
OTI!$B$1:$B$999&OTI!$N$1:$N$999
```

... or substitute the following for `OTI!$B:$B&OTI!$N:$N`,

```
OTI!$B$1:index(OTI!$B:$B, match("zzz", OTI!$N:$N))&OTI!$N$1:index(OTI!$N:$N, match("zzz", OTI!$N:$N))
```

No, that is not a typo; `match("zzz", OTI!$N:$N)` is used to find the last row for both column B and column N.